# Determine all abelian group $G$ such that $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{Z}_2^k \to 0$ is exact

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I came across the following exact sequence of abelian group

$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{Z}_2^k \to 0$

and I want to find all possible $G$. I know that the answer would be "use Ext", but I don't know what it is. Using the formal rules I can conclude that $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2^k) \cong \text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2)^k \cong \mathbb{Z}_2^k$, i.e. there would be $2^k$ extensions.

I can find only $G \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2^k$ or $G \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2^{k-1}$. Which are the others $2^k - 2$?

Comment: Be careful : $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ classifies all extensions up to isomorphisms, not just all group which fits into a short exact sequence. In other words, for a single $G$ there may be many non isomorphic short exact sequences $0\to A\to G\to B\to 0$. You found more than you thought...

Comment: @Roland You are right, I have $k$ possible ways to choose the target... but they are not $2^k$: what am I missing?

Comment: No, you actually have $2^k$ possibilities to choose a morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_2^k$.

Comment: @Roland Yes, they are, but in order to sequence to be exact the morphism shouldn't be of the form (1, 0, ..., 0) or (0, 1, 0, .., 0) or ... or (0, ..., 0, 1)?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Choose a vector $x\in\mathbb{Z}_2^k$. If $x$ is zero, then the extension will split. So assume $x\neq 0$ and let $H\subset\mathbb{Z}_2^k$ be an hyperplane not containing $x$. Then $H\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2^{k-1}$ and consider the map $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2^{k-1}\to\mathbb{Z}_2^k$ which sends $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ to $x$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2^{k-1}$ to $H$. The kernel is $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Roland I you make it as an answer I'll accept it